# Apache Spark DataFrame: df.where() with Java:List attribute

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, dataframe, where-clause

imagine you have a df like this:

```
a b  
1 1  
1 2  
1 3  
2 1  
2 2  
2 3
```

and you want to implement a generic .where functionnality;
how can you filter by a List

```
val l1:List[Int] = List (1,2)  
df.where($"b" === l1:_*) // does not work
```

or is there even a option, where you can ask sth like this:

```
df.where($"a" === l1:_* && $"b" === l1:_*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you want *IN* semantics:

```
df.where($"b" isin (l1: _*)).show()
+---+---+ 
|  a|  b| 
+---+---+ 
|  1|  1| 
|  1|  2| 
|  2|  1| 
|  2|  2| 
+---+---+
```

And

```
df.where(($"a" isin (l1: _*)) and ($"b" isin (l1: _*))).show()
+---+---+ 
|  a|  b| 
+---+---+ 
|  1|  1| 
|  1|  2| 
|  2|  1| 
|  2|  2| 
+---+---+
```